# How to list threads in c + +?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I created an application window where it catches the pid of the process, but I wanted him to get the pid of the process and the TID of thread to list them in a `ListViewer` is possible in C + +?
As in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: It is mostly operating system specific (not compiler specific), even if Visual C++ strongly suggest some kind of Windows. So please tell more about your OS (and version)!

Comment: visual-c++ suggests its windows:)

Comment: With standard c++ or c++/CLI?

Comment: operating system Windows 7